# How Akamei is packaging HLS and DASH videos?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

Latlert I've been trying to create my own simple streaming service which converts an mp4 video to HLS or DASH. For the sake of simplicity, let's focus on only HLS.

Apple is the the one how [created HLS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming) (HTTP Live Streaming) which consists of a different resulotions playlist files, and each file consists of seperate sepemts (ts, mp4 or m4a) each segment is a time range of the original video.

I've noticed the Akamei are using the same mp4 video and a query param `range` to range over the video segements.

Example of a typical segments playlist:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXTINF:6.92,
240p_noaudio_dash1.ts

#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Example of Akamei playlist:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="../../../parcel/video/78619exa.mp4?r=dXMtd2VzdDE%3D&range=0-830"
#EXTINF:6.066667
../../../parcel/video/78619exa.mp4?r=dXMtd2VzdDE%3D&range=5975-2400598
#EXTINF:6.066667
../../../parcel/video/78619exa.mp4?r=dXMtd2VzdDE%3D&range=2400599-4512749
#EXTINF:6.033333
../../../parcel/video/78619exa.mp4?r=dXMtd2VzdDE%3D&range=4512750-6575755
#EXTINF:6.066667
../../../parcel/video/78619exa.mp4?r=dXMtd2VzdDE%3D&range=6575756-8651671
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

How Akamei is gementing the same video on the fly to stream HLS and DASH?

I searched and read the HLS [Specifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/http_live_streaming_hls_authoring_specification_for_apple_devices) with no luck.

Comment: This is handled server-side.  You can do the same thing with Nginx or any other basic server that would convert the query string parameter to the appropriate request header.  Though, there's really no need to use HLS in this case.  No doubt Akamai is just offering this as a compatibility layer.  Just use the URL to the MP4 and let the browser make its own ranged requests without all this extra stuff.

Comment: @Brad Thanks for your comment.
Do you have any suggestions or documentation to follow to create the mp4 files which akamai uses to fetch video fragments as bytes range?

Comment: Surely it's just the original source MP4.